# Match URL link and ignore the page behind

Tags: php, url, detect

I have this code that will match the url and than do something, its working good but when the url has some page behind like `/board/users/somename/replies/page/2/` the code will not work. How can I only detect this part of url `/board/users/somename/replies/` and ignore the rest behind? Thanks for helping.

```
$pageURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$myurl   = '/board/users/somename/replies/';

if (strtolower($pageURL) == strtolower($myurl) ) {

echo "right";

}else{

echo "wrong";

}
```

Comment: You need to use a regular expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to match the start of the string, like this:

```
if ( strpos(strtolower($pageURL), strtolower($myurl)) === 0 )
```

You also have to ensure that the leading and trailing slashes match up, so I would suggest you  modify the first two lines of your code like this:

```
$pageURL = '/' . trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
$myurl   = '/board/users/somename/replies';
```

EDIT: I had got the slashes wrong. That's fixed now.

Comment: Thanks this works well, good to ensure the trailing slash too.

Answer (score 0):

simply try a regular expression

`if preg_match('/'.$myurl.'/', $pageUrl) {}`

this will match any url that has $myurl in it. preg_match returns 1 if the regular expression matches, and 0 if it doesn't.

if you want to exclude the URL's with page/ in it, try a negative lookahead via regex

`if preg_match('/(?!'.$myurl.'page\/)'.$myurl.'/', $pageUrl) {}`

The negative lookahead makes sure myurl/page/ is not in the URL and then you simply match for your url.

edit: for further information on preg_match check the php manual at [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use PHP [`stristr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) function to match the beggining of a string. (case-insensitive)

Try this:

```
$pageURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$myurl   = '/board/users/somename/replies/';

if (stristr($pageURL, $myurl) !== FALSE) {
    echo "right";
} else {
    echo "wrong";
}
```

I hope it helps!